# Qu'est-ce qu'un « mickouam » ?

Tags: sens, littérature, emprunts

> On part de soi, on débouche sur le confinement de la maison, première
> mémoire de l’enfance, puis, de ce **mickouam** enfumé et doucereux, on
> passe à des environnements plus limpides, à des espaces de plus en
> plus vastes qui, en inventant le monde, approfondissent le temps [...]
>
> [ [*L'Amélanchier*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TczxAAAAMAAJ&dq=l%27am%C3%A9lanchier%20ferron&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=mickouam), [Jacques Ferron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Ferron) ([1921](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/opinions/2021-01-24/hommage-a-jacques-ferron-le-dedouble.php)-1985) ]

Qu'est-ce qu'un *mickouam* ?

Comment: [_Mikiwap_](https://www.canadiana.ca/view/oocihm.50563/487?r=0&s=1) ?

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que ça ne fait aucun doute, il s'agit de « [wigwam](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/wigwam) » que l'on a aussi trouvé sous la forme « wikiwam » chez les Algonkins, et sous la forme « wikwam » chez les [Massachusetts](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oPZQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=wikiwam&source=bl&ots=e2AYgHwaGs&sig=ACfU3U0Y8_JwRv_GOHaKElc-Yz1BIqMTDA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2_IXg2rXuAhVJxIUKHVN3AMQQ6AEwQnoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Il s'agit d'un lieu d'habitation dans les deux cas et la région du globe où on trouve le second est la région du globe où on se sert du premier comme terme analogique pour référer à un lieu d'habitation.

Il y a une possible confusion avec l'Algonkin « mikouam » ([glace](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AV2bZSeXLsAC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=mikouam&source=bl&ots=5-A6hclYxu&sig=ACfU3U3b3URTqbk6PNBloUcrjjLAmpxbSQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAw6On3rXuAhUkz4UKHbFLA40Q6AEwDHoECBIQAg#v=onepage&q=mikouam&f=false)), mais « cette glace enfumée et doucereuse » n'a aucun sens, et il ne peut pas s'agir de glace.

Answer (score 0):

C'est un mot du parler de la communauté [Attawapiskat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attawapiskat) qui décrit une habitation légère, probablement une variante du mot ojibwé [wigwam](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigwam).

C'est ce qu'on peut déduire de la page 18 du document [*Omushkegowuk Women’s Traditional Practices Project: Restoring the Balance*](http://occc.ca/library/Women%27s%20Traditional%20Practices%20Project.pdf), où ce mot est transcrit en anglais *meekwam*:

> A *meekwam* was used in the spring and in the fall. We would put up a *meekwam* when camping overnight. Sometimes a *meekwam* was put up on top of the snow if there was no tent.